# Validating minimum number

Tags: validation, angular, input, min

I have this Angular 2 form:

```
<input #myInput="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="myobj.myInput" required min="0" type="number" /> 

<p>valid: {{myInput.valid}}</p>
```

When I enter `"10"` it is valid and when I enter `""` it's invalid, but when I put `"-10"` it is still valid.

Comment: It's still valid because it's not a number

Comment: Not enough information to determine what's going on.  Where's the validation code?

Comment: when is not a number how to make it to be number?

Answer (score 0):

Because `min` isn't an option for `FormsModule` validation. The [available validators](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/Validators-class.html) are `required`, `minlength`, `maxlength` and `pattern`; an empty input is invalid because you have `required`. The [`min` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-min) prevents the HTML input from decrementing below zero using the arrow keys or the up-down buttons in the input, but *isn't* used for validation; you could write a [custom validator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation) to do this.

Note that there is [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2961) discussing support for the HTML 5 validators; the fact that it's currently closed doesn't bode well for `min` and `max` getting included in the near future.